# I can't install virtualenv

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

This is showing when I try to install virtualenv in the command prompt on
`Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.344] (c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation.`

```
C:\Users\User>**pip install virtualenv**
  Collecting virtualenv
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/f1/2e07e8ca50e047b9cc9ad56cf4291f4e041fa73207d000a095fe478abf84/virtualenv-16.7.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Installing collected packages: virtualenv
  **ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\program files\\python38\\Lib\\site-packages\\virtualenv.py'
           Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.**

  WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: "Consider using the --user option" did not help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not need to install virtualenv anymore: since Python 3.3 it's bundled as part of the standard install, you can just call `python -mvenv <params>` and that's equivalent to the old `virtualenv <params>` invocation.

There are some platforms which unbundled it (as well as `ensurepip`) but since you're on windows and likely used an official-ish installer it *should* be present.

Answer (score 0):

Open your command prompt as administrator before running the command. The program files directory is protected from modification and requires administrative privileges to modify.

Answer (score 0):

are you under administrative right in the command promt??